# How to add custom variable to URL Request of controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.8

I have added this to the Controller:

```
public function updateMethod(Request $request)
{
   $i = 1;
   dd($request->input_name_1);
}
```

Now I wanted to change to this:

```
public function updateMethod(Request $request)
    {
       $i = 1;
       dd($request->input_name_$i);
    }
```

But I get this error:

### **syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'**

So how can I add my custom variable to `$request` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom variables by using bind string in one variable and passing it to `$request->`
like below code

```
$i = 1;
$tmp  = "input_name_".$i;
dd($request->$tmp);
```

using this you can get values of custom variables

Answer (score 1):

You can just use basic concatenation in this code. like this one.

```
public function updateMethod(Request $request)
{
   $i = 1;
   dd($request->"input_name_".$i);
}
```